# Minzinc: Using switching between objectives dynamically

Tags: minizinc

I have a minizinc model for scheduling a project that currently optimises for total makespan.
However, sometimes the total cost of the scheduled project is more important.
I would like to:

1. Use a value in my .dzn (i.e. objective, 1 = makespan, 2 = costs, 3 = some other objective)
2. based on that variable switch between different objectives/solve commands in my .mzn

I tried to use `if <bool-exp> then <exp-1> else <exp-2> endif` but that doesnt seem to work for the search sequence/ objective.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples what you can do.

If neither works for you, please give more context (preferably a complete MiniZinc model + data) what you try to do and the error message you get.

What I know there is no way to place the complete `solve` expression in a `if-then-endif` expression. I.e. the following is **not possible**

```
% ...
if mode = 1  then
   solve :: int_search(x,first_fail, indomain_split) minimize z1
elseif mode = 2 then
   solve :: int_search(y,anti_first_fail, indomain_min) maximize z2
else 
   solve satisfy
endif
;
```

First two variants which might work for simpler cases.

**Approach 1**

Using an variable for the optimal value (here `z`) to be minimized and then place the value in an `if-then-else-endif` clause. Note that you have to be careful to get the sign correct for the different cases. Also, the domain of `z` must be selected to cover the appropriate case.

```
% int: mode = 1; 
% int: mode = 2; 
% int: mode = 3; 
int: mode = 4; 

var 0..10: x;
var 0..10: y;

var int: z;

constraint
  if mode = 1 then
     z in 0..100 /\
     z = x*2*y
  elseif mode = 2 then
     z in 0..20 /\
     z = x+y
  elseif mode = 3 then
     z in -100..0 /\
     z = -(x*2*y)
  else
      z in -20..0 /\
      z = -(x+y)
  endif
; 

solve minimize z;
```

**Approach 2**

A similar idea is to move the `if-then-else-endif` clause to the `solve` part:

```
int: mode = 1; 
% int: mode = 2; 
% int: mode = 3; 
% int: mode = 4; 

var 0..10: x;
var 0..10: y;

solve minimize
   if mode = 1 then
      x*y
   elseif mode =  2 then
      x+y
   elseif mode = 3  then
      -x*y
   else
     -(x+y)
 endif;
```

The drawback of this version is the there is no variable (`z`) where one can set a proper domain.

**Approach 3**

A third - and then one I would use for more complex models - is to use the MiniZinc/Python interface: https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .

Comment: @MaxS Great. If you think it solves your problem, please accept it as a solution.